# Are EMV terminals required to support offline PIN as well as online PIN in US market?

Tags: emv

It is my understanding that in the US 100% of EMV transactions (contact and contactless) are expected to be performed online.  If so, why would a payment gateway be requiring a US terminal to support offline PIN (if online is offered) for CVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is international interoperability.

Not all countries joined the EMV band-wagon at the same time, and hence different countries support different types CVMs. Many markets still only support Offline PIN, or even Signature.

Hence, both cards and terminals support multiple CVMs, but do so in a prioritized order. The idea is that the card and terminal negotiate the highest common CVM that both support, in order to carry out a transaction.

If the American terminals only supported Online PIN, then travellers might fail to transact there, since they their cards might not support Online PIN. This could be a valid decision, but in some areas (like retail at airports) this is unacceptable.

Similarly if Americans went to overseas to countries where Online PIN is not supported, they'd expect their cards to support either Offline PIN or signature in order to facilitate payments there.

This gives most customers the best chance of at least transacting -- albeit with a 'lower' CVM.

Answer (score -1):

From EMVCo, LLC

Chip Technology , A  Guide  to  EMV Version 2.0  Copyright  ©  2014  EMVCo,  LLC.    All  rights  reserved.

“The  second  feature is  a  new  CVM of  offline  PIN.  While  ***the  use  of  offline  PIN is entirely  optional***, it  is  possible  to  use  an  EMV  chip  card  to  verify  a  PIN entered into  the  terminal PIN  pad  by  the  cardholder and  therefore provide  a  PIN based cardholder verification  method  available  for all  offline  and  online  transaction acceptance  environments,  including  below  the  floor limit and  offline  only.”

Comment: this does not explain the regional requirement